# Port 3306 busy but no process using it

Tags: mysql, unix, docker, process, console

I'm starting to play with docker and docker-compose and I found a problem with the mysql container. I'm using the official mysql:latest image. When I run the docker-compose up i get this error:

`Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use`

To be sure that my docker-compose.yml doesn't have problem, I tested the port 3307 and everything worked fine. But I want to use the standard 3306.

Of course I killed my local mysql daemon, but the error persisted. So I run

`netstat -lnp | grep 3306`

and that's what I found:

`Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address    Foreign Address   State       PID/Program

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306    0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN      -`

I also executed `lsof -i TCP:3306` and I didn't get any result.

How can I free the 3306 port? Thanks!

Comment: do you see any mysql with this? `ps aux|grep mysql`

Comment: Are you running the netstat with sudo, on the host?

Comment: I logged as root into the console and it showed up: mysqld was not properly killed.- 
Even if I used sudo to kill the process, it restarted but only for root! I'm not sure why this happened! However killing as root (not with sudo) it worked properly.

Thanks for your help guys :-)

Answer (score 3):

Okay Lets Try with Sudo

```
sudo netstat -lpn |grep :3306
```

you will see proceesID of that port, Execute with these

```
kill -9 PID //PID processID used by 3306 Port
```

In here -9 is for force kill, Hope this Helps