# Docker: Error response from daemon: Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is already allocated

Tags: mysql, shell, docker, web, mariadb

I'm new to Docker and I can't seem to get my mariadb container running. I have just freshly installed Docker on Macbook Pro running High Sierra.

I've simple used this command:

```
docker run --name db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test -d -p 3306:3306 
mariadb
```

Which is supposed to create an image and run the container from it. But I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming 
external connectivity on endpoint db 
(d4d6631ae53d644b5c28a803d5814a792c7af6925ebcf84b61b49b4a0fe30f4b): 
Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:3306 failed: port is 
already allocated.
```

So far I may have used MySQL in the far past, but I'm pretty sure I don't have anything running on port 3306.

I have also tried not adding the -p tag, it will run when I use this but when i execute `docker ps` it will show `3306/tcp` and NOT `0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp` as the PORT.

I have also tried just having to port tag as `-p 3306` but this will show `0.0.0.0:32769->3306/tcp` as the PORT in `docker ps`.

I would love some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `lsof` command to check if a service / process is using the port `3306`.

```
$ lsof -i tcp:3306
COMMAND PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  721 krisnik   34u  IPv4 0x348c24a60c9d72a9      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql (LISTEN)
```

Now kill / stop the service.

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Re-run your Docker container. It should work fine as the required port is released.

Edit - 1

If `lsof` doesn't catch the process, `netstat` can also be used.

```
sudo netstat -lpn |grep :3306

kill -9 PID //PID processID used by 3306 Port
```

Ref - [Port 3306 busy but no process using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271159/port-3306-busy-but-no-process-using-it)

Comment: check `docker ps`. Is there any other docker container which was previously started holding on to the port?

Comment: I've just today started using it. `docker ps` and `docker ps -a` are both completely empty.

Comment: I did have MySQL installed on my machine and in the system preferences it DID show a server running. I've turned it off now, and created a new image. But now it won't run the container. Looking into it...

Comment: How come lsof didn't catch it?

Comment: It worked! I kinda fixed it myself, but you did send me in the right direction, thanks. And I have no clue about lsof.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44271159/port-3306-busy-but-no-process-using-it -- This could be the reason.

Comment: Had the same issue even after I've killed `mysqld`, i had to go to Mac OS System Preferences and disable MySQL Auto start-up. And then docker did started the container ok.